# Mergesort doesn't sort specific arrays

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, mergesort

My  Java MergeSort is unable to sort certain combinations of arrays. The first array sorts fine, however when I swicth the 9 with a 6 the 6 ends up after the 7. If I switch the 9 with an 11 then I get an indexoutofboundsexception. Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated

```
import java.util.Arrays;


public class SortMerge {

public static void sort(int [] array, int beg, int end){
    if(beg<end){


    int mid =(beg+end)/2;
    sort(array,beg,mid);
    sort(array,mid+1,end);
    mergesort(array);
    }
}

public static void mergesort(int [] array){
    int beg =0;
    int end = array.length;
    int mid = (beg+end)/2;

    int second= mid+1;
    int first =0;
    int[] temp = new int [array.length];

    for(int i=0;i<temp.length;i++){
        if(first<=(mid) && second<=(end)){
            if(array[first] <= array[second]){
                temp[i] = array[first];
                first++;
            }else if(array[second]<array[first]){
                temp[i] = array[second];
                second++;
            }
        }else{
            if(first>mid){
                temp[i] = array[second];
                second++;
            }else if(second>end){
                temp[i] = array[first];
                first++;
            }
        }

    }

    for(int s=0; s<array.length; s++){
        array[s] = temp[s];
    }

}

public static void main(String [] args){
    int [] one= {0,1,3,5,7,9,4,6,8,10};
    int [] two= {0,1,3,5,7,6,4,6,8,10};
    int [] three= {0,1,3,5,7,11,4,6,8,10};
    sort(one,0,one.length-1);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(one));

}

}
```

Comment: You need to merge **only** the sorted sections. Your `mergesort` blindly merges the whole lot.

Comment: so does that mean the sort method is only running the mergesort method once?

Comment: It's running it for every recursion, but it is merging the _whole_ array about the middle. You are sorting the two sections `beg -> mid` and `mid -> end`. You are then merging `0 -> middle` and `middle -> array.length`. This is not what you want.